# How to use AdMob banner in multi-view app (UINavigationController)?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, admob

I'm new to ios. What is the correct way to put AdMob banner in the bottom of the screen for all pages of the app?

In android I used fragments for this purpose (there was a fragment for navigation and view for AdMob which was always on the bottom)